# mysql to mysqli connect code failing?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've seen this [code](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) that's been floating around, and also the [fixed?](http://www.anddev.org/post91169.html#p91169) version. Basically I've gotten this to work:

```
mysql_connect("host","client_name","client_pw");

mysql_select_db("database");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

$output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
```

but for some reason I feel it should be in mysqli. I'm new, and tried to write an equivalent mysqli OO code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "client_name", "client_pw");
$mysqli->select_db("database");

$q = "SELECT * FROM table";

 while($e=$mysqli->fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;
     print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
```

It fails. I've tried other combinations, such as preparing a query and executing it, and setting that as $e, but all fail.

Do I have to manually build the array for the json_encode or something?

Maybe a better question is why I want to reinvent the wheel, but this has been bothering me.

Comment: Could you define "it fails" ?

Comment: Do you have `mysqli` extension compiled / loaded in your php instalation?

Comment: People that peddle irresponsibly horrible code need to be punished.  @Danedo, you would do well to avoid both of those "tutorials," they are based on *worst practices*.

Comment: 1. `$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");`
2. `$q = "SELECT * FROM table";`

Don't you see, by chance, any difference between these codes?

Comment: @Nanne noted, I'll be more specific on my future questions. @dev-null-dweller I'm pretty sure, as other code does work, but I'll check. @Charles unfortunately that is all I have, and I'm not exactly experienced enough to roll my own :(    @Col. Shrapnel yea, I caught that earlier. One is just a bloody string. A string! But that is why I added 'tried other stuff' or something.   Any way thanks for the insights, I'll be sure to find a solution, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see you are not *one* with the database.  Let us perform an exercise.

Close your eyes, breathe in, breathe out.

Relax.

You are *one* with the database.

You are *one* with the code.

Repeat after me.

#### Prepare.

#### Bind.

#### Execute.

Repeat it.

Again.

This is your new **mantra**, my friend.

You've accidentally skipped a step in your existing code.   Let's throw it out and start over.

I am going to show you how to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), one of the better ways PHP has to communicate with a database.  It's less *convoluted* than the mysqli extension.

```
// Make sure these variables contain the correct data.
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
// Ask PDO to throw exceptions instead of warnings.
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// Here's our SQL.  We're getting back a PDOStatement object here.
    $sh = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?');
// That question mark is a placeholder.  bindValue lets us replace the question mark
// with the specified data.  This is called a prepared statement.  The end result is
// *complete and total immunity* from SQL Injection, if performed correctly.
    $sh->bindValue(1, "I'm looking for a bar that is equal to this.");
// Okay, we've bound everything, let's run the query.
    $sh->execute();
// And assuming there are no errors (note my severe lack of error handling),
// we should now have our complete list of data from the database.
    print_r($sh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

// Alternatively, we could pass bound variables as an array to execute:
    $sh = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?');
    $sh->execute(array( "I'm a bar!" ));

// And of course, we can use variables in the binding...
    $bar = 746;
    $sh = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?');
    $sh->bindValue(1, $bar);
    $sh->execute();
```

PDO's support for [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [placeholders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) makes it *one of the best choices* for database access in modern PHP.

(mysqli also has access to [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), but it forces you to [also bind result variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), and that can be *damned awkward* under a lot of circumstances.)

`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns a multidimensional array.  The outer array is numerically indexed, each value being a row.  Each row is a string-keyed array, where the keys are column names and the values are the data from the database.  [There are a few other things that `fetchAll` can do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), though I haven't found many of them to be useful.  You can also [fetch one row at a time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

You can probably pass the results directly to `json_encode`, if you'd like, and not suffer too many problems.

Understand that you will want to add appropriate error detection to this code.  I have omitted it here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{

   $db = new mysqli("your_host_ip", "your_username", "your_pass", "your_db", 3306);

   if ($db->connect_errno) throw new exception(sprintf("Could not connect: %s", $db->connect_error));

   $sqlCmd = "select * from users order by username";

   $result = $db->query($sqlCmd);

   if(!$result) throw new exception(sprintf("Invalid query : %s", $sqlCmd));

   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Here is how to do it with mysqli OOP
After the line $q= etc.  -add the following code..

```
<?php
$result=$mysqli->query($q);
while($e=$result->fetch_assoc()){
              $output[]=$e;
}
 print(json_encode($output));
?>
```